# Oracle APEX print with API

Tags: oracle, plsql, pdf-generation, oracle-apex

I need to export a report saving it in PDF format. I created a button that submits to a new page, which performs the following piece of code:

```
APEX_UTIL.DOWNLOAD_PRINT_DOCUMENT (
        p_file_name           => 'myreport123',
        p_content_disposition => 'attachment',
        p_application_id      => :APP_ID,
        p_report_query_name   => 'MY_REPORT_QUERY',
        p_report_layout_name  => 'MY_REPORT_LAYOUT',
        p_report_layout_type  => 'xsl-fo',
        p_document_format     => 'pdf'
)
;
```

`MY_REPORT_QUERY` and `MY_REPORT_LAYOUT` are defined in the shared components. When I press the button, it downloads a pdf file, but it looks empty or corrupted.
What could be wrong? Do I need to specify the print server? And what about the field `APP_ID`?
I can confirm that both the query and layout work when I download the report by directly redirecting the page to the url of `MY_REPORT_QUERY`.
Thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: What API are you using, perhaps Apex Office Print?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question... Do I need some extra program to make it work? I do not know what is installed, because i am not the admin of the system, but I am almost sure we have the basic setup with no extras.

Comment: what version of APEX are you using ??

Comment: @Discipulus I had never used the APEX_UTIL printing, so I assumed it was a separate program for it, for any more complex printing you need something else, like AOP. But I guess just printing the output of a query can be handled by APEX itself. So never mind me

Comment: @TineO no problem, and thanks.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez, I am using APEX 5